# SBCL VLIME use CFFI

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, asdf, quicklisp

I'm trying to learn common lisp but am having a very difficult time setting up my environment.

I'm trying to wrap a c library using `cffi` but I can't seem to get sbcl to find the `cffi` package. I have previously installed it using `(ql:quickload :cffi)`.

I'm using vlime.

I've tried the following:

```
(defpackage my-package
  (:use :cl :cffi))
(in-package :my-package)
```

in which case I get the following error:

```
The name "CFFI" does not designate any package.
```

when I try to compile the file using `\of` in vlime.

This error persists if I add `(ql:quickload :cffi)` or `(asdf:load-system :cffi)` before or after the previous code. In addition, it seems to put vlime into an unrecoverable state.

If I remove `:cffi` from `:use` then I get the error

```
Package CFFI does not exist.
```

The error persists when trying to use `ql` as well.

I've also tried using `(require :cffi)` and all permutations of combinations with the `ql` and `asdf` imports.

I'm very close to giving up on common lisp. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I also have `:depends-on (:cffi)` in my `asd` file.

Comment: "If I remove :cffi from :use then I get the error" -> you can still access cffi with its `cffi:` prefix (if it was loaded).

Can you post your .asd file?

Comment: And how do you load your .asd file? You can do `(load "project.asd")` (or better yet `(asdf:load-asd "/path/to/project.asd")`) and then `(ql:quickload "project")` from the REPL, or use an editor shortcut, but I'd advise to do without shortcuts to not mix difficulties.

Comment: Are you following a tutorial we could refer to together?

Comment: I'm not following a tutorial. I'm using the default asd file created by `cl-project:make-project` but with `:cffi` in `depends-on`. The `eval-when` in the accepted answer worked but I'm still unclear as to how people normally develop asd systems using vlime. In slime do you 1) open a repl, 2) load whatever systems/packages you need, and 3) compile/load the file(s) you're working on? Since vlime's repl is read-only this workflow doesn't seem possible but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes we do 1-2-3: start Slime (which launches a REPL), compile and load the *system* (C-c C-k or load or asdf:load-asd), quickload the system, and then use the functions defined in whatever package that is now available. It is the .asd system that defines QL dependencies and source files where a package definition awaits to be loaded. We don't "load a package".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that CFFI is loaded at compile time.  A single-file solution is

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload :cffi))

...

(defpackage :foo
  (:use :cl :cffi)
  ...)
```

If you are using ASDF (which is more scalable) then make your system depend on CFFI and compile and load the *system* in the first instance.

Comment: I've made my system depend on cffi. How can I load that system when editing that file (say `foo.lisp`). Can you do this in a slime/vlime workflow?

Comment: No idea.  It looks like `slime-asdf` adds support for ASDF to SLIME for Emacs.  I don't use it though: I just compile & load systems from the REPL.  Once the prerequisites are loaded you don't have to care for the life of that image, which might be weeks.

Comment: So to load and develop the system you're currently working on, you manually compile/load in the repl and then send new forms individually to the repl?

Comment: If the system has more than one file you really need to load it before starting work on bits of it.  For single files I'd generally not have a system but just use (a shim around) what I gave.